Distribution of Noisy Linear Dynamical System over time
Suppose we are given a linear dynamical system
$$
x_t = Ax_{t - 1} + \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)
$$
where $A$ is orthogonal, $x_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ is a normal distribution.
Given the initial state $x_0$, does $x_t$ follow a well-behaved a distribution (i.e. a normal distribution)?
I have applying tools from stochastic calculus, but am struggling to get it work. If anybody has any insights, it would be deeply appreciated!

Yes, the state is distributed according to a Gaussian distribution: $x_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_t,\Sigma_t)$, where the evolution of the mean is described by $\mu_t = A \mu_{t-1} + \mathbb{E}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I) = A \mu_{t-1}$ and the evolution of the covariance by $\Sigma_t = A\Sigma_{t-1} A^\top + \sigma^2 I$.
In your case it holds $\mu_t = A^t \mu_0 = A^t x_0$ and $\Sigma_t = \sigma^2 \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} A^k(A^\top)^k = t\sigma^2 $.
